# how do i make my for loop do the same thing for different arguments without writing more cases?

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

so i wrote code that simulates a bank balance checker that what it does is output a number when you give it a account number.

```
print("welcome to bank!\n")
bank = {
    "sam": [1234, 150],
    "bob": [1235, 250],
}

print("please select an action:\n")
print(
    "1. check balance \n2. withdraw money \n3. deposit money \n4. exit\n"
)
action = int(input("selected action:"))
accnuminput = int(input("please enter account number:"))
if action == 1:
    if accnuminput == (bank["sam"][0]):
        print(bank["sam"][1])
```

what i did before was just add another elif every time i added an account, like so:

```
if accnuminput == (bank["sam"][0]):
    print(bank["sam"][1])
if accnuminput == (bank["bob"][0]):
    print(bank["bob"][1])
```

but i understood that if you have a lot of accounts that is not viable, so i wanted to ask is there any way to do this so that the same formula works for any account ask for and that i don't have to write a new case for every entry?
thank you.

Comment: How about: `user = "sam"` and then `bank[user][0]`? 

Comment: If you want to look up by account number, make that the dictionary key, instead of the name.

Comment: you can loop over the dictionary values: `for acctnum, balance in bank.values():`

Comment: @AKX do you mean something like asking before what the name of the user is, then from that, to check if the name entered is connected to the account number entered and if so, output the balance?

Comment: Write a `class` for the account and another for the user and maybe a third for the bank, it’s more flexible and functions for each use case. Python has also a switch what is named [match Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put the user name into a variable (here, I'm prompting it from the user), and use it as a key for your `bank`.

I also changed the data structure a bit so it's easier for a single user to have multiple bank accounts; it's now (conceptually) `{user: {account: balance}}`.

This will crash with a KeyError if an user enters an invalid account number, but that's the next thing for you to solve.

```
bank = {
    "sam": {1234: 150, 1236: 800},
    "bob": {1235: 250},
}

print("welcome to bank!\n")
user = input("please enter your name:")

if user not in bank:
    print("user not found")
    exit()

print(f"hi {user}, your account numbers are {sorted(bank[user])}")

print("please select an action:\n")
print("1. check balance \n2. withdraw money \n3. deposit money \n4. exit\n")
action = int(input("selected action:"))
accnuminput = int(input("please enter account number:"))
if action == 1:
    print(
        f"{user}, the balance of your account {accnuminput} is {bank[user][accnuminput]}"
    )
```

An example run:

```
welcome to bank!

please enter your name:sam
hi sam, your account numbers are [1234, 1236]
please select an action: (...)
selected action:1
please enter account number:1234
sam, the balance of your account 1234 is 150
```

Comment: thank you, this helps, i just have 2 questions, first, does the f after the parenthesis after the print mean\do anything? it is not familiar to me. second, {bank} is now a dictionary of dictionary's, where the key is the name of the user and the value of the inner dictionary is a key value pair of the account number and balance, correct?

Comment: (1) [A formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). (2) You got that right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
if accnuminput == (bank["sam"][0]):
```

you can check if the bank number "1234" is present in the any of the account details (account details is the list containing the bank number and balance.

So the final code will look something like this:

```
print("Welcome to the bank!\n")

bank = {
    "sam": [1234, 150],
    "bob": [1235, 250],
}

print("Please select an action:\n")
print("1. Check balance \n2. Withdraw money \n3. Deposit money \n4. Exit\n")

action = int(input("Selected action: "))
accnuminput = int(input("Please enter account number: "))

if action == 1:

    # Check if the account number exists in the bank dictionary
    if accnuminput in {acc[0] for acc in bank.values()}:

        # Access the balance using the entered account number
        for name, acc_details in bank.items():
            if acc_details[0] == accnuminput:
                print(f"Balance for {name}: {acc_details[1]}")
                break
        else:
            print("Account not found.")
```

But the more appropriate solution would be to restructure your dictionary by using bank account number as key and name, balance as values:

```py
print("Welcome to the bank!\n")

bank = {
    1234: {"name": "sam", "balance": 150},
    1235: {"name": "bob", "balance": 250},
}

print("Please select an action:\n")
print("1. Check balance \n2. Withdraw money \n3. Deposit money \n4. Exit\n")

action = int(input("Selected action: "))
accnuminput = int(input("Please enter account number: "))

if action == 1:

    # Check if the account number exists in the bank dictionary
    if accnuminput in bank:

        # Access the balance using the entered account number
        account_details = bank[accnuminput]
        print(f"Balance for {account_details['name']}: {account_details['balance']}")
    else:
        print("Account not found.")
```

Here we are using dictionary of dictionaries but you could also use dictionary of lists.

Comment: how would you do it using a dictionary of lists? would you do something like this?
     `bank = {
             1234  :  [ "sam" , 150]
     }`
and if so how would that affect the second part of the code because
`{account_details['name']}: {account_details['balance']} ` 
doesn't work anymore

Comment: Yes, you could use:

bank = { 1234 : [ "sam" , 150],
               1235 : ["bob" , 250]
            }

but using dictionary of dictionaries would be the optimal method because if you have multiple parameters in the bank details, it would be easier for you to get those details using the name of the parameter.